# How to extract the present Latitude and Longitude values from Emulator in android

Tags: android, google-maps, android-emulator

**What i am trying to do**::

I am trying to log the present location(`Latitude`,`Longitude`) 
I am using a android emulator for testing

---

**What i have done**::
I have opened the `DDMS` and manually pushed the `Latitude` & `Longitude` co-ordinates to the emulator and pressed the send button

---

**My Question** :: How can i extract those Values from emulator and print as a Log

Answer (score 2):

Add the following permissions.

```
<manifest ... >
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission. ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
   <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET" />
</manifest>
```

Make your class implement LocationListener and add the following code.

```
locationManager = (LocationManager) getSystemService(Context.LOCATION_SERVICE);
locationManager.requestLocationUpdates(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER, 0, 0, this);

@Override
public void onLocationChanged(Location location) 
{
    Log.d("LatLng", "Latitude:" + location.getLatitude() + " Longitude:" +     location.getLongitude());
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You get Lat/Long for Mapview using projection

```
void foo() {
    Projection proj = mapView.getProjection();
    IGeoPoint p = proj.fromPixels(e.getX(), e.getY());
}
```